# Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Using regular expression what would be the best way to find an unknown pattern in a string? Is this even possible using Regex, I would just like a bit of guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by "an unknown pattern"? Your question is very unclear at the moment. Could you give an example?

Comment: you're gonna have to be a little more specific than that

Comment: `.*` That would match everything except a newline. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Kevin, that's perfect! It matches every unknown pattern known to mankind.

Comment: @Cpfohl, so it is the mother of all [known unknowns](http://www.slate.com/id/2081042)?

Comment: What i meant was determining the pattern from analyzing the string, but the pattern is not known beforehand when the string is being analyzed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused about what regular expressions are for. They do not determine underlying repeating/mathematical/musical/etc. patterns in data; they find matches to a *specific* pattern.

So if I understand your question correctly, then, no, this is not possible using a RegEx.

Comment: Okay thanks, thats what I thought as well.

Comment: @Delanoy - Sounds like this is the answer to your question as written, but it is probably not the answer to the actual problem you have.  I suggest you open a new question, with **examples**.  State directly and specifically what problem you are trying to solve. What kind of patterns are you looking for?  Should it be able to tell you the next value in the sequence {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}?  Or something less numeric?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Expresso here:

http://www.ultrapico.com/

Play with the tool and learn more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

If the patterns that you want to match are unknown, then you can always match you input string against a set of 'known patterns' and discard the unmatched strings.

Comment: I would not have a set of known patterns, I would need to be able to determine it by analyzing the string.